# bash function check previous result

Tags: bash, function

In bash s there a way to create a flow of function that will prevent next function call if there is an error:

i.e.

```
function msg_ok {
      echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'): OK+: $1 $2" | tee -a "/tmp/log_me"
}
function msg_er {
      echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'): ERR: $1 $2" | tee -a "/tmp/log_me"
}
function msg_check {
     tail last_line_of_log | grep "ERR"
     exit 
}

function first {
       msg_check
       do_your_thing
       msg_er "nothing works"
       else
       msg_ok "go on to next"
}

function second {
       msg_check
       do_your_thing
       msg_er "nothing works 2"
       else
       msg_ok "go on to next 2"
}


first
second
third
```

I mean is there a way to call first second and third in different order and stop if previously there was msg_er called ?

Comment: In function you should use `return` not exit, of course `0` and `1` is used for true and false.

Comment: Use `set -e` to stop the program as soon as an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy. Just execute:

```sh
first && second && third
```

The `&&` operator in bash means that the command as second operator is executed only if the command as first operator exits without error.

No need of `msg_check`.

You may want to correct your script as follows:

```sh
function msg_ok {
      echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'): OK+: $1 $2" | tee -a "/tmp/log_me"
}
function msg_er {
      echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'): ERR: $1 $2" | tee -a "/tmp/log_me"
}

function first {
  do_your_first_thing && { msg_ok "go on to next"; return 0 } || 
    { msg_er "nothing works"; return 1 }       
}

function second {
  do_your_second_thing && { msg_ok "go on to next 2"; return 0 } || 
    { msg_er "nothing works 2"; return 1 }       
}


first && second && third
```

But as far as I understand your problem, I would just do:

```sh
do_your_first_thing && do_your_second_thing && third
```